# Group By SQL Statement - Get countries with more than 5 cities

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to pull the countries that have more than 5 cities.

Tables:

**City** `city_id, city, country_id, last_update`

**Country** `country_id, country, last_update`

I think I am very close to getting this figured out, but I'm not quite there. Any pointers?

```
SELECT DISTINCT country
FROM country C, city O
WHERE O.country_id = C.country_id AND O.country_id
 IN (SELECT country_id FROM city group by country_id having count(country_id) > 5);
```

Comment: You should read this article. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select country
from country inner join city on city.country_id = country.country_id
group by country
having count(distinct city) > 5
```

Comment: use count(city) in case they have nulls... +1 from me though.

Comment: yeah, the OP wasn't specific on that.  you might have to even use `count(distinct city)` in case there are dupes

Comment: true point... and that is probably better for them anyway (distinct that is)

Answer (score 2):

```
Use the below query..

   SELECT country
    FROM country C
     JOIN city O
    ON  O.country_id = C.country_id 
    GROUP BY country
    HAVING count(distinct O.city)>5
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
select countryid, count(distinct city_id) from country c join city ct c.country_id=ct.country_id
group by countryid 
having count(distinct city_id) > 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       country
FROM   country C
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT city_id)
              FROM city CITY
              WHERE CITY.country_id = C.country_id
              GROUP BY CITY.country_id 
              HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT city_id) > 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

The below query works for your requirement.

```
   SELECT C.country
     FROM country C
    INNER JOIN
          city O
       ON  O.country_id = C.country_id 
   GROUP BY C.country
   HAVING count(distinct O.city)>5;
```